# How to mock a class and test a functionality of it

Tags: vb.net, testing, mocking

I have a class with two functions but i like to mock one function and test the functionality of the other ?

```
public class Alpha
   Function F1() As String
        SendMail()
        return "Sample"
     End function


       '''code to send mail 
        End sub
End class
```

Here I would like to test the functionality of F1() and like to mock SendMail(). Is it possible?

Now I am doing like this:

```
       Dim objAlpha As New Mock<Alpha>
       objAlpha.Setup(Function(x) x.SendMail())
       Dim lstrReturnValue As String =objAlpha.Object.F1()
```

Is it the right way? But I am facing issues. Please provide a way to write mock test for this scenario.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same question.

Comment: @monkey blot :there is concept called partial mocking u can try that